# How to call multiple instance of the SAME function with different arguments in onClick React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, sorting, events

I am implementing sorting of table in Modal Window. I wrote this code but it is incorrect.

```
<ExtendedModalBar
  list={this.state.modalList}
  onCancel={this.handleExtendedModalClose}
  onSave={(...args) => this.handleSaveFromModal(...args)}
  selectedItems={this.state.modalItems}
  show={this.state.showExtendedModal}
  type={this.state.modalType}
  //onClick={this.onSort('', )}
  sortColumn={this.onSort('isSecure', this.state.modalList); this.onSort('profile', this.state.modalList)}
/>
```

My function:

```
 onSort = (column, dataToSort) => (event) => {
    const direction = this.state.sort.column ? (this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'desc';

    dataToSort.sort((a, b) => {
      if ( typeof(a[column]) === 'string' && typeof(b[column]) === 'string' ) {
        const nameA = a[column].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        const nameB = b[column].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase

        if (nameA < nameB ) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }
        // names must be equal
        return 0;
      }

      if( typeof(a[column]) === 'number' && typeof(b[column]) === 'number'){
        return a[column] - b[column];
      }

      if(typeof(a[column]) === 'boolean' && typeof(b[column]) === 'boolean'){
        const firstBool = +(a[column]);
        const secondBool = +(b[column]);
        return firstBool - secondBool;
      }

    }
    );

    if (direction === 'desc') {
      dataToSort.reverse();
    }

    this.setState({
      sort: {
        column,
        direction,
      }
    });
  };
```

My sorting function accepts two arguments, columnName and data. if I call the function in onClick only one time, it sorts only one column. how to call function multiple times and pass different arguments, i.e different column names ?

Comment: Did you try something like `onClick={() => ... the code in sortColumn...}` ? If you call twice `onSort` on **the same** set of data, does it sort it appropiately?

Comment: don't understand a bit. I need to pass every columnName as a string to my onSort function in order to sort every column of table not just one exact column. Yes the set is the same but the function accepts also columnname

Comment: please look at my function. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related with the following: the `onClick` attribute expects  *just one function*. I would try with something like this:

```
onClick={(event) => 
    this.onSort('isSecure', this.state.modalList)(event); 
    this.onSort('profile', this.state.modalList)(event);
}
```

or some more elegant yet equivalent code. Hope it helps - Carlos

Comment: if i wrote this: onClick={(event) => 
    this.onSort('isSecure', this.state.modalList)(event); 
    this.onSort('profile', this.state.modalList)(event);
}    the compiler says it is syntax error expected "}"

Comment: I have overcome syntax error problem, but now only one column is sorted, the second  not.

Comment: strange! Could you add a `console.log` or `alert` statement in the `onSort` function, to be sure that it is called just once?

Comment: your code above gives syntax error. I wrote this:  sortColumn={(e) => {this.onSort('isSecure', this.state.modalList)(e);
            this.onSort('profile', this.state.modalList)(e);}}   and syntax error removed, I added console log, I got logs twice, but only one column sorted

Comment: Hence the problem lies in the function. I guess that while the **criteria** to sort is related with the chosen column only, the **array** you are sorting is the whole array.  If you want the columns to be sorted independently of one another, it would be more convenient to have a different array for each column. Your `modalList`  could be an object including all the arrays. Of course this would make the `render` more complicate, but I cannot imagine an easier alternative. Recall that the function you pass e.g. to `Array.map` has an additional argument for the _index_.

Comment: my modalList is array of objects

Comment: What should I do in this case ?  How to rewrite my onSort function?